# What's the simplest method in Ruby of telling if SQLite returned a row?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am very new to Ruby and I am using it with SQLite.

I have written register and deregister functions but I am stuck writing a function to tell if a given user is registered in the database.

This is the current code:

```
 def registered?(l)
  db = SQLite3::Database.new "database.db"
  db.execute("SELECT user FROM t1 WHERE user = ?, ", l[1])
  end
```

What is the simplest method to tell if SQLite returned a row to this query?

**Update**

Thanks for the suggestions on how to do it. Here is the updated code:

```
 def registered?(l)
  db = SQLite3::Database.new "database.db"
  results = db.execute("SELECT user FROM t1 WHERE user = ?, ", l[1])
  !results.empty?
 end
```

and I am using it:

```
  if registered?(@nick)
   ...
  end
```

but I guess this isn't right, because my code under `registered?(@nick)` doesn't get triggered when the `@nick` is registered. I have both in the same `class User`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't "evolve" questions like that. It invalidates existing answers. Ask separate questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

response should not be an empty Array:

```
res = db.execute("SELECT user FROM t1 WHERE user = ?, ", l[1])
if !res.empty?
 # some row is returned
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of your execution is an array ([SQLite3::Execute](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/database.rb#L110-L111)):

```
class User
  def registered?
    db = SQLite3::Database.new "database.db"
    results = db.execute("SELECT user FROM t1 WHERE user = ?, ", self)
    !results.empty?
  end
end
```

Then you'd say `@user.registered?`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you check my updated code in the question?

Comment: where is the registered method located?  In the user class?